# how to preserve sub-domain and base path in the proxy_redirect final url in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

Basically I have the problem in setting up the proxy_redirect properly in [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx). Basically I want to perform proxy redirect like this:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/test1/test2/test3 -> http://subdomain.another.com/test1/test2/test3
```

here subdomain and url path (i.e. /test1/test2/test3) keeps on changing, so here I have to grab them from the redirect url and pass it to final url.

I was trying like this:

```
proxy_redirect ~^(http://[^\.]+)\.domain\.com/(.+)$ http://$1.another.com/$2;
```

Please provide any solution to do this.

Comment: Read nginx proxy module docs. You doing something completely wrong

Comment: @AlexeyTen i think it's regex. Please suggest something. I have gone through the docs but little confuse here in regex.

Comment: And do you realize that this directive works only with `Location` header?

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite, using a regex, will preserve the path while changing the domain:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         subdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  subdomain.another.com/$1;
    }
}
```